# Disabling a Textbox Using TextChanged Event

Tags: c#, textchanged, disabled-control

The form I am using requires a copy pasted URL. I am trying to have a textChanged event that will check the url as soon as it is pasted, telling the user whether it is valid or invalid. I also want to be able to lock out the textbox when this happens, with a message saying something like "Processing...".

The problem is with the code below, the textbox is never disabled, the program will do the checkUrl() method and the textbox is never disabled even though it is first to execute (I assume it is but the fact there is a function call right underneath it is messing around with something or getting higher priority).

How do I go about making the control visually disabled while the method runs?

```
private void urlTxtBx_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    urlTxtBx.Enabled = false;

    checkUrl();

    urlTxtBx.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: You're re-enabling it right after checkUrl();. How long does the method take? If it's just validating a URL then i doubt it's very long so disabling the textbox makes little sense?

Comment: Are you sure that it is not disabled? What if the `checkUrl()` is executed too fast so you cannot see it? Debug it to be sure.

Comment: Put a messagebox after you disable the textbox, that way you can pause the code and see if it worked, if it did it's likely it just executes `checkUrl()` fast enough to reenable the textbox before you can notice.

Comment: No that is not the issue as I have removed the enabling part of it and it will still wait for the other method. It is not a quick method and downloads the url source and begins to sort through it.

Comment: @cheeseman what do you expect to see after desabling the textbox? Please re-run your code with just the part of disabling the `Textbox` and check if you can write into it.

Comment: Try disabling the textbox inside of the checkUrl(); method

Comment: @schaliasos I have tried that, it disabled itself (greys out) after the method below it finishes.

Comment: You may want to reenable it there too after it's finished running

Comment: @Duane it does the same as before, I think this may be an issue with the way the form works (updating visuals) similar to a progress bar I think I need a background worker...

Comment: @cheeseman please add this `Application.DoEvents();` before disabling the `TextBox`.

Comment: But what problem are you trying to solve? Why do you want to disable the textbox when someone is typing or pasting something into it?

Comment: @Schaliasos that solved it :) If you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @CodeCaster This is a textchanged event, the pasted url is being checked so the user will not be doing any more typing for now.

Comment: What happens when the user tries to type his url in instead?

Comment: @cheeseman I don't see how disabling the textbox will aid in that. As soon as `TextChanged` is fired, you can check the contents. What if the user wants to type something after the URL they pasted, or what if they want to type the whole URL?

Comment: There are specific instructions and the textchanged event only triggers on a pre defined set of characters. This method takes a while to complete as well as it downloads source code from the net and begins to sort it and auto complete the form.

Comment: What are the pre defined set of characters that trigger the text changed method? AFAIK, it fires as soon as a character is typed/pasted into the text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because the Application needs to complete all the active threads before disabling the `TextBox`. Please try the following code:

```
private void urlTxtBx_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    urlTxtBx.Enabled = false;
    Application.DoEvents();
    checkUrl();
    urlTxtBx.Enabled = true;
}
```

This will let the UI to be updated. For more details check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx).

Comment: Almost. You'll have to call `DoEvents()` after disabling the textbox, because the UI then needs to be updated (which `DoEvents()` does, by letting the paint messages being processed).

Comment: This is correct, but you have the Application.DoEvents(); line in the wrong place. It needs to be called after disabling the textbox.

Comment: Ok, I will fix it. Thank you.

Comment: That won't quite work; your `DoEvents` call needs to be *after* setting `.Enabled = false`.  Also, DoEvents is *horrible*.

Comment: @DanPuzey disabling a textbox in a change event is also horrible.

Comment: @CodeCaster not for what I am using it for :P